# resampling from fractional to integer sampling rate

Tags: sampling, downsampling

I have data recorded at 1000Hz and other physio data recorded, somehow, at 1960.8 Hz (510 microsecond samples). Ideally, I would like to be able to downsample the 1960.8 hz signal to line up with the 1000Hz signal.  Any suggestions? I am familiar with matlab or Python.

Comment: Why not just use Matlab's `resample` command (or Python's equivalent)? You will lose all signals above 500 Hz, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `resample` command mentioned as follows to accomplish this:

```
y=resample(x,1250,2541); % x is the input signal
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That worked, except I changed the argument to: resample(x,1250,2451)